How can I avoid being hit with Telegram Flood Wait limit when trying to join multiple groups using their invite links?
I'm trying to join a lot of telegram groups on one account. I've made a script in python that uses telethon to do the job but it fails miserably and gets rate limited extremely fast.
Ignore the "time.sleep(2)" being set at 2 seconds, I normally run it at 5 minutes each
from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
from opentele.api import API
from telethon.errors import FloodWaitError
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
import time
import asyncio

# Replace these with your own session name and phone number
session_name = 'your_session_name'  # e.g., 'account1'
phone_number = 'PHONE NUMBER'        # Your phone number, including country code

# Load group invite links from a file
with open('groups.txt', 'r') as file:
    group_invite_links = [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()]

async def join_groups():
    api = API.TelegramDesktop  # Use Telegram Desktop's official API
    client = TelegramClient(session_name, api=api)
    
    # Start the client and log in
    await client.start(phone=phone_number)
    
    for invite_link in group_invite_links:
        try:
            # Extract the invite hash from the invite link
            if 'joinchat' in invite_link:
                invite_hash = invite_link.split('/')[-1]
            else:
                # Handle t.me/+inviteHash format
                invite_hash = invite_link.split('/')[-1].lstrip('+')
            
            await client(ImportChatInviteRequest(invite_hash))
            print(f"Joined group: {invite_link}")
            
            # Add a delay to avoid triggering flood wait
            time.sleep(2)  # Adjust the delay as needed

        except FloodWaitError as e:
            print(f"Flood wait for {e.seconds} seconds")
            time.sleep(e.seconds)  # Wait out the flood wait time

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error joining group {invite_link}: {e}")

    await client.disconnect()

# Run the async function
asyncio.run(join_groups())

I tried prolonging the sleep time, it does work but it would take me a month to join all the groups I wish to join with a higher sleep time, it would already take approximately 17 days with the script provided above.

Stackoverflow is probably the wrong place to ask how to subvert security/spam features of other platforms.

I'm not looking to spam telegram though :(
I just want to know if there's a way to join groups at a faster rate without spamming telegram, thus not triggering the flood wait error.
